# opencv android : changing `Cv.Type` results in pixel magnitude change

Tags: android, opencv, jpeg, steganography, dct

I am using OpenCV on **android** to build a a **DCT steganography** app.
I have to change the `CvType` of the image mat according to the different processes like `dct`, `idct`..etc.

Steps: **(and required type of `mat` for that step)**

0. Load image bitmap and get image `mat` **(CvType.CV_8UC4)** from it.
1. Convert image from RGB to YCrCb
2. Divide the image into blocks of 8 x 8 blocks.
3. Center pixel values around 0 [0-255 => -128-127] **(CvType.CV_32SC1)**
4. Apply DCT transformation to get DCT coefficients for the block. **(CvType.CV_32FC1)**
5. Quantization [divide the DCT coefficients with quant matrix]
6. Now substitute the LSBs of the non 0/1/DC coefficients with our secret message. **(CvType.CV_8SC1)**
7. inverse quantization**(CvType.CV_32FC1)**
8. inverse DCT
9. [0-255 <= -128-127]
10. YCbCr to RGB
11. Get bitmap from image `mat` **(CvType.CV_8UC4)**
12. Save the bitmap as jpeg.

#### Problem :

In the `11th` step I have to convert image mat to the original type `imOut.convertTo(imOut, imIn.type())`.
By testing, I have found out, that at this step a small percentage of pixel values get changed (example -  one of the DCT coeff :  `13` to `12`) which changes the steg message from `aaaaaa` to `aaaa!a`

Any solutions ?

Comment: Either don't save to jpeg, or implement jpeg steganography properly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35396977/lsb-dct-based-image-steganography) for example.

Comment: @Reti43 yes saving as jpeg will create a problem, but currently the problem I'm facing is at step 11, which I have checked by printing the DCT coefficients before and after step 11.